# Cakephp 3.x order by date with different date notations

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a row (varchar) with date notations retreived from digital camera's.
This notation differs between types and models.

Now, I want to order this row by datetaken ASC or DESC.

```
->order(['Searches.datetaken' => 'DESC']);
```

This is not working correct with values like `20100115` and `20160302164444` (example).

To fix this, I want to use `STR_TO_DATE()`
But how do I use this in a correct way in Cakephp 3.x
This is not working:

```
->order([STR_TO_DATE(Searches.datetaken,'Ymd') => 'DESC']);
```

Comment: You should format the data _before_ it is written into the database!

Comment: Ok, I'll start my DeLorean DMC-12 and go back to the year 2009

Comment: Cool, if you have some spare time left, try to snitch Michael Jacksons propofol! In case you cant get your hands on some plutonium, you could of course simply transform the data in your database instead... also **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609102/order-by-on-mysql-stored-function-in-cakephp-3** (bad peformance though, no indices, so try to avoid it)